# SharePoint Lookup Column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have two lists on SharePoint imported through excel:

1. System (speadsheet -- contains 10 columns)
2. Server Inventory (speadsheet -- contains 14 columns)

I would like to link the two together. For example, in the system list, one of the columns displays the server names. I would like find out information about that particular server that is stored in the server inventory. I could do this with the lookup column no problem. However, System contains unique server name values. But Server Inventory has many items with the same server name. With the lookup column it only displays one of the findings when there are altogether 4 items that have the server name. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Is there any way SharePoint could show me the filtered Server Inventory list when I click on one of the servers in System list?

Any help would be much appreciated.
**SharePoint 2010**

Answer (score 1):

I might not be reading your question correctly, but I think this link might be helpful
http://blog.erikvl87.nl/2010/10/how-to-create-a-cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010/

It shows how to make one column of a list get information from another based on a value of the first list.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to open up a filtered list from within a list? maybe through a link or hyperlink?

Comment: Not that I have come across yet, but using the link I was able to create a list for a helpdesk that, once you chose a category of problem, changed another field to be a dropdown with several subcategories by having a list like you described, with several items having the same name, and varying descriptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is pretty easy actually, connected Web parts can help you in this case..

Just drop the List Web Part of both the lists in a single page, now select the System Web Part.. click drop down arrow on the top right -> Connections -> Send row data to -> you should see Server Inventory web part..

Now you should see configure connection dialog, where you choose the field you want to filter in Consumer Field Name (i.e. the lookup column) and ID column in Provider Field Name..

That's it you should see an arrow at the start (selector), selecting which should filter the results in Server Inventory web part..

Please have a look at:

[Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA101785157.aspx#_Toc287442210)

[Connect Web Parts in SharePoint 2010](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2010.html)